# What is the difference between asp and asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

I am developing web application using asp.net, but i want to work on asp i have to install asp or can we write  the code using asp.net, what is the main difference between these two asp,asp.net. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP is the legacy version of active server pages that was created before the .NET framework. It works on IIS and is written in VBScript or Javascript.

ASP.NET is the newer version built on top of the .NET framework and is written in VB.NET or C#

IMO, you should spend your time learning and using ASP.NET as classic ASP is rather ancient in terms of web technologies and will likely not be supported for much longer (merely guessing there..)

You may also want to consider looking at ASP.NET MVC as a possible solution as well.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use classic ASP in a .NET environment running IIS. If that is what you're asking.